# UISearchController background color with no text

Tags: ios, swift

I created a table view with the following code:

```
    searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: self)

    presentViewController(searchController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

In the viewDidInitialize method. When text is entered, the table view displays as expected:

[image]

If no text is entered into the search field, I cannot see the table view. Is there a trick to showing the table view in this state or is there any other way to customize the background? I've tried setting dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation to false but that did not work.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Works if you pass nil instead of self

```
searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
```